# Excel pivot table exclude some column totals

Tags: excel, pivot-table

I am using an Excel 2010 pivot table to display data. I need the sub totals in most columns but some columns display percentages and totaling the percentages is not correct and displays confusing values. Is there any way I can choose which columns not to total.

Comment: Right click on the column title. And use Field Settings.

Comment: I'm not sure why you have included that column into the pivot table if you don't need the totals in it, unless you are asking how to make it display the total instead of a percentage or some other calculation.

Answer (score 4):

It's hard to make sure I'm accurately addressing your question without more detail about your data, but I will provide a simple example.

**Recommendation**

I would suggest that you put all measures/values in the Values area of the Pivot Table, and not in the Row Labels. That way, you will not get Row sub-totals for values.

In order to address the non-additive totals and sub-totals for your percentages, I recommend that you remove the pre-calculated percentages from your Pivot Table Values and instead use a Calculated Field that is calculated within the Pivot Table itself from the base data, and will provide correct aggregate totals and sub-totals.

**Example**

See below:

[image: Example]

**Method**

In order to create a Calculated Field using the Ribbon, select your Pivot Table, and then go to PivotTable Tools --> Options --> Fields, Items, & Sets --> Calculated Field.
Then, enter a name for the new Field (CalcPercentSoldUnits in my example below), as well as the formula definition for the field ( =UnitsSold /UnitsProduced in my example below). Click 'Add' to create the field and then 'OK' to exit the dialog box.

Now you have created a derived field not in your base data table, but in your Pivot Table, which can be used just like a normal field. You can also see that it will calculate totals and sub-totals correctly because instead of adding constants, it is calculating based on the sums of other constants from which the percentages are derived.

In some cases depending on how your data is structured, you may need to create a Calculated Item instead of a Calculated Field.

I hope this helps - if this doesn't address your situation, please post additional examples of your data and desired results. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

I have the same problem.  Some Columns should be totaled, and others should not be.  The only thing I figured out is to Grand Total all columns, then format those cells in the Grand total so that the font color matches the background color.  This hides those selected Grand Totals from being viewed and/or printed.  I experimented by expanding the Pivot Table rows, and the formatting for the selected cells followed into the new cell(s) and when I removed some of the rows, the formatting followed as well.

Answer (score 1):

Wherever you don't want to show the total columns simply hide the column in the total section. I couldn't find any other way to do it.

Answer (score 1):

I think I have a similar situation and a great answer for presentation purposes. I'm billing a customer for unbilled items; my pivot shows Qty, rate, and total missed revenue (qty*rate) for each month. Having a sum of Qty and Revenue makes sense for each month, but totaling the rates of the items doesn't. Pivot table and value options are an all-or-none solution. Rather, I just selected the totals I needed to hide and formatted them with white font color (blue for the grand total). My pivot table looks great now with this band-aid approach.

Answer (score 0):

Be careful about things like distinct/unique counts.  This method helps with percentages, but you don't want to sum or average or otherwise aggregate unique counts.  I would prefer to be able to just exclude a total for a single field but haven't found a method to do so.